# Two Values in CSS Attribute Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, attributes

How to target two values in Attribute Selector without duplicate css selector?

This is with one:

```
a[href^="mailto"]:after {
        content: "";
    }
```

This is what I need (this example is not working):

```
[href^="mailto http"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
a[href^="mailto"]:after,
a|href^="http"]:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: So, it is not possible without duplicate css selector?

Comment: I don't think so since you are trying to target two different elements, you need two selectors.

Comment: Unless you want to use Sass, you could use `@each`: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each